# Append an array to each entry of another array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to generate an array containing an array for each of the items

the code i tried:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 );
$array2 = array('how','are','you') ;

foreach( $array2 as $key => $value ){
    $value = $array2;
}
```

result of this code

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "how"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "are"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "you"
}
```

The desired result is an array where each of the words contains the following values:

```
 how  = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

 are  = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

 you  = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assign the array of numbers in each words.

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 );
$array2 = array('how','are','you') ;
$newArray = [];
foreach( $array2 as $key => $value ){
   $newArray[$value] = $array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using implode() to make it string

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 );
$array2 = array('how','are','you') ;
$arr = [];
foreach( $array2 as $key => $value ){
   $arr[$value] = implode(",",$array);// using implode 
}
print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [how] => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
    [are] => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
    [you] => 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative approach for achieving desired output. Here we are using `array_fill` and `array_combine` to get the desired output. With this `array_fill(0, count($array2), $array);` we are creating an array of values with `$array` to the count  of `$array2`, Then we are using `array_combine` to make `$array2` as keys `$values` as values.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/799781)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 );
$array2 = array('how','are','you') ;

$values=array_fill(0, count($array2), $array);//here we are creating an array with $array
print_r(array_combine($array2, $values));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_combine, check the [live demo](https://eval.in/799783).

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 );
$array2 = array('how','are','you') ;
print_r(array_combine($array2, array_fill(0, count($array2), implode(',', $array))));
```